# pygame.mixer.Sound().play() gives no error but actually does not play

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, python-3.6

I am trying to play a .wav file with pygame

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
s = pygame.mixer.Sound('absolute path to file')
s.play()
```

it gives no error, but it seems like it doesn't play anything.
This is the complete output

```
pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
```

installed pygame via pip in a conda python 3.6 enviroment. mac book pro 2019 with macOS Mojave

Comment: Have you made sure the file was not empty, and was accidentally erased? It happened to me once.

Comment: You could also consider including information about how you installed pygame, and your OS info.

Comment: @User12692182 yeah I'll do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As bashBediam said the problem was that the code was ending not giving time to the audio to play. i fixed that doing like this.

```
import pygame
pygame.mixer.init()
s = pygame.mixer.Sound(path)
channel = s.play()
while channel.get_busy():
     pygame.time.wait(100)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a line at the end :

```
input ('Press enter to continue.')
```

and you will hear it. Your script is ending before it has a chance to play the sound.

Comment: The problem with this is the user has to click enter to hear any sound. This isn't ideal for say, a gun shot sound. The sound should occur when any event happens.

Comment: consider that the wav file is part of a chatbot, it should be reproduced automatically. However thanks to you i understood why it is not working